# delete after confirm alert message not working

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5.8

when I want to delete a getsub the confirm not working in my view just work for parent ...what is the problem???? but the confirm alert do not working in first foreach that there is $getsub...
I think some thing is wrong in my onclick attribute but i could not recognize what is it??

#### it is my view

```
<tbody>
<?php
 $parents = $cats->where('parent',0)->all();
 $counter = 1 ;
 function GetSub($id,$cats,$counter) {

   $width = 35 * $counter ;
   $getsub = $cats->where('parent',$id)->all();

   foreach ($getsub as $value){

   $edit = '<a href="'.url('admin/yekta/category/'.$value->id.'/edit').'" 
         class="table-action-btn"><i class="md md-edit"></i></a>' ;
   $delete = '<a 
      href="javascript:;"onclick="$.Notification.confirm(\'warning\',\'top 
      center\',\' آیا برای حذف این دسته مطمئنید؟\' , 
      '.url('admin/yekta/category/'.$value->id.'/destroy').')"  class="table- 
      action-btn"><i class="md md-close"></i></a>' ;

 $edbtn = (Auth::user()->can('edit video')) ? $edit : '' ;
 $dlbtn = (Auth::user()->can('delete video')) ? $delete : '' ;

echo "<tr>
<td><i class='fa fa-square-o'></i> ".$value->id."</td>

<td style='padding-right: ".$width."px;'><i class='fa fa-square-o'></i> ".$value->name."</td>

<td style='text-align: center;'>
<div class='btn-group'>
$edbtn
$dlbtn
</div>
</td>";

if($value->has_next){
$counter ++ ;
GetSub($value->id,$cats,$counter);
}

 echo '</tr>';

}

}
?>
@foreach($parents as $value)

<tr>
<td><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> {{ $value->id }}</td>

<td><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i> {{ $value->name }}</td>

<td style="text-align: center;">
<div class="btn-group">
@can('edit video')
<a href="{{ url('admin/yekta/category/'.$value->id.'/edit') }}" class="table-action-btn"><i class="md md-edit"></i></a>
@endcan
@can('delete video')
 <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.Notification.confirm('warning','top center',' آیا برای حذف این دسته مطمئنید؟' , '{{ url('admin/yekta/category/'.$value->id.'/destroy') }}')"  class="table-action-btn"><i class="md md-close"></i></a>
@endcan
</div>
</td>

</tr>

<?php
if($value->has_next){
 GetSub($value->id,$cats,$counter);
}
?>

@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code

Comment: You indent poorly

Comment: I edited them a little .... I did not write these codes ...I have to  improve them